# For $T: V \to V$, suppose $A = A^*$ where $A = [T]_\mathcal{X}$. Find another basis/matrix where $B \neq B^*$ for $B = [T]_\mathcal{Y}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ that *does not come with an inner product*. For $T: V \to V$, suppose $A = A^*$ where $A = [T]_\mathcal{X}$. Is it possible to find another basis/matrix where $B \neq B^*$ for $B = [T]_\mathcal{Y}$?

In answer this question, I'm trying to show that the property of "self-adjoint"-ness, the operator $T^*$, can only be defined when $V$ is equipped with an inner product. But I'm failing to find a counter-example. How would one go about finding this?

Comment: $A^*$ here denotes the complex conjugate. The answer is: it **is** possible. To see it, take a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix (not the identity) as $A$ with reals on the diagonal and choose an invertible matrix $S$ which is not unitary. A random choice should do. Then $SAS^{-1}$ is not selfadjoint. But $SAS^{-1}$ is the matrix representation of $A$ with respect to another basis.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp. Thank you. How do you know to choose such a matrix $S$? As in, how do you know to choose a transition matrix that is not unitary? The intuition escapes me.

Comment: If you choose S unitary, $SAS^{-1}$ will be selfadjoint since the inverse of S equals its adjoint.